# Display list of places near the user's current location in a UITableView in Xcode using a Google Places API

Tags: swift, uitableview, google-places-api

I'm creating an app in Xcode that will have a popover screen over the map view that allows the user to select from a list of nearby locations based on their current location. I have tried several ways to do this but have not accomplished this. I'm relatively new to coding and the Google Places documentation is a bit too vague for me to work out.

That being said I already have Google Places implemented (downloaded, linked, API key, etc.), so I'm just trying to find the right way to display nearby places in a list view. I am creating this using Swift. Here's what I have so far, so if it's a mess:

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlaces

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.nearbyPlaces()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func nearbyPlaces() {
        placesClient.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoodList, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
                for likelihood in placeLikelihoodList.likelihoods {
                    let place = likelihood.place
                }
            }
        })
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return GMSPlaceLikelihoodList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Test"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are actually close to solution,

1. Create an outlet for tableview reference
2. Create a variable `likeHoodList` for holding result of [GMSPlacesClient](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_places_client)
   request.
3. When [GMSPlacesClient](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_places_client) callback done and store result in `likeHoodList` and
   reload tableview.
4. Don't forget to change `cellForRowAt` to write place name etc. and
   count of places is your tableview row count.
5. in callback parameters placeLikelihoodList is a
   [GMSPlaceLikelihoodList](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_place_likelihood_list) reference.
6. [GMSPlaceLikelihoodList](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_place_likelihood_list) has two properties, likelihoods and
   attributions
7. likelihoods is an array of [GMSPlaceLikelihood](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_place_likelihood)
8. [GMSPlaceLikelihood](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_place_likelihood) has two properties, place and likehood
9. place is a [GMSPlace](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_place) reference which has properties about that
   place like name, placaeID, coordinate etc.

Here is a complete solution,

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlaces

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient!
    var likeHoodList: GMSPlaceLikelihoodList?
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.nearbyPlaces()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func nearbyPlaces() {
        placesClient.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoodList, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
                likeHoodList = placeLikelihoodList
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let likeHoodList = likeHoodList {
          return likeHoodList.likehoods.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = UITableViewCell()
        var place = likeHoodList.likelihoods[indextPath.row].place //this is a GMSPlace object
        //https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_place
        cell.textLabel?.text = place.name
        return cell
    }
}
```

**Update**,

It seems that you didn't init delegate, change viewdidload like this,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.nearbyPlaces()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great! The only issue I'm having is populating the table with the "place.name" value. It is returning the error: Value of type 'GMSPlaceLikelihood?' has no member 'name'

Comment: @M.Spencer, yes that's my bad, it should be `var place = likeHoodList.likelihoods[indextPath.row].place`, updated my answer.

Comment: awesome response! Unfortunately it still doesn't seem to be populating... I don't have any errors but the list is still blank, I'm sure it's a silly mistake I'm making

Comment: have you tried print out or debug and check if likeHoodList.likehoods has any elements. Maybe you forgot to enable location services? "you must request permission to use location services. " https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/current-place

Comment: @M.Spencer, I assumed that you have already call `requestAlwaysAuthorization` any other place in your project and have location services enabled when user shows this screen.

Comment: I just did as you suggested, I have enabled location services and I did `print(self.likelihoodList!.likelihoods.first!)` which did comeback with the first likelihood

Comment: Did you create delegates on storyboard? just add tableview.tableView.dataSource = self in viewdidload, and put break point on tableview events, be sure that's are called on running.

Comment: Tried that and still can't seem to get it to work, sorry if I'm wasting your time

Comment: Np, but let's summarize, location services is enabled and you get data and print the place, and you are sure that google service working. Did you check if numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt working?

Comment: Yes to all, it prints all the information about the place so that seems to be working, it just must be the connection to populating the cells... how would I test to see if the numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt functions are working? Sorry I'm a bit new to all this

Comment: @M.Spencer, create break point and run again or just print something inside functions. http://www.cimgf.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Screenshot-121212-1214-AM.png

Comment: looks like the issue is where it returns the number of rows based on the list count

Comment: but you said neither are working, at first you must have them working. did you create init delegate, see my updated answer.

Comment: Ok that works but runs into the error at the list count... if I put a number in there, say 3, it populates and returns the first three correctly

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a mac right know and cannot debug my code, check my update on numberOfRowsInSection.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much!

Comment: how could I convert this to cloud firestore with field name location and using the type "geopoint" ?